# How to use GitHub API to get a repository's dependents information in GitHub?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

When I was using GitHub API v4 to get some information, I can easily get dependencies by using `repository.dependencyGraphManifests`. But I can't find any way to use GitHub API v4 to get the dependents information, though I can see it in the `Insights->Dependency Graph->Dependents`.
I want to know if there is any possible way to get the dependents information in a GitHub repository? Whether GitHub API or something else.

Comment: There are a few CLI tools which can do it (quite slowly by crawling github). https://github.com/github-tooling/ghtopdep or https://github.com/nvuillam/github-dependents-info for example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you can get the dependents project using Github API (Rest or Graphql), one way could be to use scraping like the following [python](/questions/tagged/python) script :

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

repo = "expressjs/express"
page_num = 3
url = 'https://github.com/{}/network/dependents'.format(repo)

for i in range(page_num):
    print("GET " + url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    data = [
        "{}/{}".format(
            t.find('a', {"data-repository-hovercards-enabled":""}).text,
            t.find('a', {"data-hovercard-type":"repository"}).text
        )
        for t in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "Box-row"})
    ]

    print(data)
    print(len(data))
    paginationContainer = soup.find("div", {"class":"paginate-container"}).find('a')
    if paginationContainer:
        url = paginationContainer["href"]
    else:
        break
```

[Try this python script](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/github-dependents-repo)

Comment: There is [`DependencyGraphManifest `](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/dependencygraphmanifest/), but at the time of this writing it only includes `dependencies` without `dependents`.

Comment: @Bertrand Martel: I tried to find you on linkedin to credit you, but without success... Add me if you like ! https://www.linkedin.com/posts/nicolas-vuillamy_stats-markdown-badges-activity-6997663878016868352-sBBi?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop

Answer (score 6):

I improved and packaged all the answers in a python command line utility [github-dependents-info](https://github.com/nvuillam/github-dependents-info)

```
pip install github-dependents-info
github-dependents-info --repo nvuillam/npm-groovy-lint --markdownfile ./package-usage.md --sort stars --verbose
```

In addition to already existing features, it can:

- Output as text, JSON or markdown file
- Manage multiple packages in a single repo (ex: [megalinter](https://github.com/oxsecurity/megalinter))
- Retry HTTP requests when failing
- Generate shields.io badges

[image]

[Example result Link](https://github.com/oxsecurity/megalinter/blob/main/docs/used-by-stats.md)

Answer (score 4):

Based on Bertrand Martel's answer (@bertrand-martel), do not forget to add the following code so that you are not stuck between 1st and 2nd pages. In other words, it will be going forward, and then backward; because there is initially only one `<a>` tag, whereas the next page has two of these, so it chooses 1st one ("previous") and returns to the previous page.

Code:

```py
...
    paginationContainer = soup.find("div", {"class":"paginate-container"}).find_all('a')
    if len(paginationContainer) > 1:
        paginationContainer = paginationContainer[1]
    else:
        paginationContainer = paginationContainer[0]
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Building on top of @Bertrand Martel 's answer, the following is a version of his code that does not require knowing the `page_num` beforehand:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

repo = "expressjs/express"
url = 'https://github.com/{}/network/dependents'.format(repo)
nextExists = True
result = []
while nextExists:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    result = result + [
        "{}/{}".format(
            t.find('a', {"data-repository-hovercards-enabled":""}).text,
            t.find('a', {"data-hovercard-type":"repository"}).text
        )
        for t in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "Box-row"})
    ]
    nextExists = False
    for u in soup.find("div", {"class":"paginate-container"}).findAll('a'):
        if u.text == "Next":
            nextExists = True
            url = u["href"]

for r in result:
  print(r)
print(len(result))
```

Keep in mind that it can run very long if there are many dependents.

Comment: Hi @muvaf, first of all, thanks for your answer. I'm using your script to get all the dependent repos for a project. e.g. psf/requests. requests has more than 1.4 million dependent repos on github, but when I use this script, it only can grab 2831 results. And I can see it navigated 111 pages. Do you why it stopped collecting more results? Thank you very much.

Comment: After running a couple of more times, found the total number of results is not consistency, e.g. the last run got 2842 results and navigated 116 pages.

Comment: Looks like it is because the page is not fully loaded. I have replaced requests.get with selenium. Now it is getting all dependent repos.

Answer (score 2):

I was working with a large repo and what I needed was dependent repos with **least a certain amount of stars**.

So I modified @muvaf's answer, to only look for the dependent repos with at least `min_stars_cnt` stars.

You can also modify the `result_cnt` variable for the script to stop when you have a certain number of repos - in case you don't want to wait until you scrape all the dependents:

```py
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

repo = "mochajs/mocha"
url = 'https://github.com/{}/network/dependents'.format(repo)
nextExists = True
min_stars_cnt = 50
result_cnt = 100
result = []
while nextExists and len(result) < result_cnt:
    # uncomment the line below to see progress.
    # print("url: " + url + "  " + "cnt: " + str(len(result)))
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    tmp = [
        {
             "name": "{}/{}".format(
                t.find('a', {"data-repository-hovercards-enabled":""}).text,
                t.find('a', {"data-hovercard-type":"repository"}).text
             ),
             "stars": int(t.find("svg", {"class": "octicon-star"}).parent.text.strip().replace(',', ''))
        }
        for t in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "Box-row"})
    ]
    tmp = list(filter(lambda repo: repo["stars"] > min_stars_cnt, tmp))
    result = result + tmp
    nextExists = False
    try:
        for u in soup.find("div", {"class":"paginate-container"}).findAll('a'):
            if u.text == "Next":
                nextExists = True
                url = u["href"]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("waiting for 10 seconds...")
        time.sleep(10)
        nextExists = True

for r in result:
  print(r["name"] + ", " + str(r["stars"]))
print(len(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

A [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) script (similar to the python accepted answer) that lists repos with their stars and forks. The script either returns a json array if piped, or yields a ruby repl otherwise.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'json'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

$repo = ARGV.fetch(0, "rgeo/rgeo")

Repo = Struct.new(:org, :repo, :stars, :forks)

url = "https://github.com/#$repo/network/dependents"
repos = []

while url
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(url))
  doc.css('#dependents .Box .Box-row').each do |el|
    repos << Repo.new(
      *el.css('.f5 > a').map(&:inner_text),
      *el.at_css('.d-flex').content.delete(" ,").scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
    )
rescue
  binding.irb
  end
  url = doc.at_css('.paginate-container > .BtnGroup > .BtnGroup-item:nth-child(2)').attr("href")
end

if $stdin.tty? && $stdout.tty?
  # check `repos`
  binding.irb
else
  jj repos.map { { name: "#{_1.org}/#{_1.repo}", stars: _1.stars, forks: _1.forks } }
end
```