# List dependents of a Github repository via Github API

Tags: dependencies, repository, project, github-api

The Github webpage shows on every repo's insights page what repos are dependent on it:
https://github.com/django/django/network/dependents

Via the Github API you seem to only get the repos that your repo depends on not the repos that are dependent on your repo. See `Repository.dependencyGraphManifests`:
https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#repository

Did I miss something or is it just not possible to get the dependents via the API?

Comment: I don't think it's possible at this time, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58772379/2614364)

Comment: It seems you can't via API, but you can with a CLI: https://pypi.org/project/github-dependents-info/

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can install [github-dependents-info](https://pypi.org/project/github-dependents-info) and use it in your Python script like other APIs.

For example, the following script:

```
from github_dependents_info.gh_dependents_info import GithubDependentsInfo
import json

gh_deps_info = GithubDependentsInfo(
            'aimhubio/aim',
            debug=False,
            sort_key='name',
            min_stars=0,
            json_output=True,
            badge_markdown_file=False,
            badge_color='informational',
            merge_packages=True,
        )

dependents = gh_deps_info.collect()
with open('aim_dependents.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(dependents, f, indent=4)
```

is equivalent to the CLI command:

```
github-dependents-info --repo aimhubio/aim -p -j > "aim_dependents.json"
```

Try it out and give me a like!

Comment: This seems like a pretty bad brute force approach (not that any better option seems available). I've been running this for 5 hours and it's still not completed. It appears to scrape the pages on Github, and there are around 15k pages of results for the repository I'm looking at.

Comment: This is indeed a Tool based on scraping that i built from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64053407/list-dependents-of-a-github-repository-via-github-api , it can take several days on popular repos, but as far as i know there is no other solution :/