# Search Github repos by filename and its file content

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

For example, I want to know how to implement a project that uses Django and Stripe. So I want Github repos that uses these dependencies. I can think of two example ways to know that in this case:

1. repositories that `**/urls.py` contains `views.stripe_webhook` AND `**/views.py` contains `from django` (no requirements.txt approach)
2. repositories that `requirements.txt` contains `Django` and `stripe` (requirements.txt approach)

Either way, it need to search text content in files in repositories.

So here, how can I do something like this, using Github API, Github advanced search, or Github Graphql (, or something else)?

Comment: just download the `requirements.txt` and look for django/stripe?

Comment: @dan1st that's not a fundamental solution. To do that, I need to crawl/scraping Github, it's inefficient and probably against to the ToS.

Comment: Just download `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<reponame>/<username>/master/requirements.txt`. You wouldn't need to do any scraping.

Comment: I mean, I wanted to search the entire Github, but not specific repositories, like you can from the search bar or search API.

Comment: You might be able to use the dependency graph (especially dependents) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58734176/10871900).

Comment: Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382069/search-for-code-in-github-using-graphql-v4-api?rq=1) could help you.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look.